# Python: Code suddenly not working - "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on this code that has an array of calculated years for which a windspeed of X threshold may return to a given lat/lon, returning a heat map of sorts showing the value in years. I had the code working fine before, but after running again a couple weeks later with no changes, I am getting this attribute error related to the pcolormesh function from matplotlib.pyplot. The plot is now entirely blank and I have tried numerous solutions to no avail. The traceback is shown below if you have any idea what may be going on. Thank you!

```
    <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 181, longitude: 361, year: 30)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -105.0 -104.8 -104.5 ... -15.5 -15.25 -15.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 44.25 44.5 44.75 45.0
  * year       (year) int64 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 ... 2014 2015 2016 2017
Data variables:
maxwind    (year, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
<xarray.DataArray 'maxwind' (latitude: 181, longitude: 361)>
array([[      inf,       inf,       inf, ...,       inf,       inf,
          inf],
   [      inf,       inf,       inf, ...,       inf,       inf,
          inf],
   [      inf,       inf,       inf, ...,       inf,       inf,
          inf],
   ...,
   [      inf,       inf,       inf, ..., 1212.577 , 1212.577 ,
     478.0651],
   [      inf,       inf,       inf, ..., 1212.577 , 1212.577 ,
     478.0651],
   [      inf,       inf,       inf, ...,  622.2772, 1212.577 ,
     478.0651]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -105.0 -104.8 -104.5 ... -15.5 -15.25 -15.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 44.25 44.5 44.75 45.0
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/ww/TCWindPDF.py", line 44, in <module>
cs = plt.pcolormesh(lons,lats,RP.values,cmap='gnuplot2_r', vmin=min,vmax=max) # figure out why this isnt working

File "/Users/ww/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2801, in 
pcolormesh
__ret = gca().pcolormesh(

  File "/Users/ww/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1459, in 
pcolormesh
    result = self._pcolormesh_patched(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/ww/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1485, in 
_pcolormesh_patched
    shading = kwargs.pop('shading', 'flat').lower()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to traceback here is problem.

- Method `_pcolormesh_patched` looks first kwarg `shading` and if it does not exists it looks for kwarg `flat` and tries to use them as string (expecting that object has `lower()` method.
- `_pcolormesh_patched` is called by method `pcolormesh` in cartopy.mpl lib which just add all kwargs it has to the call.
- `pcolormesh` is called by method `pcolormesh` in matplotlib. And that method always add `shading` as one of kwargs. It get it from it own argument **defaulting to None**
- You call `pcolormesh` method in your `TCWindPDF.py` without `shading` argument.

Resulting matplotlib add shading kwarg as default value `None` and that fails because None does not have method `lower()`.  `flat` kwarg is never used because in this chain `shading` is always present because `pcolormesh`in `pyplot.py`adds it.

If your code worked before, could you have updated your lib and that behavior was changed a bit. The problem can be fixed by adding `shading` argument your call `TCWindPDF.py` line 44. I don't know what value you could give to it, but probably you can find options from Mathplotlibs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may stumble across a similar issue, the solution I discovered was incredibly simple:

Change 'plt.pcolormesh' to 'plt.colorbar'

The command must have been changed or decommissioned since I had last used it, so it no longer worked, but now works the same.